# Anti-symmetric part of $\mathbf{24}$ in $SU(5)$

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, tensors

(In this question all representation (reps) will be denoted by their dimension)

I have a rep which branches into $(\mathbf{24}\oplus \mathbf{24})_{anti}$ of $SU(5)$ I have been told that the tensor associated with this is:

$$\psi_\mu \phi^\nu-\psi_\nu\phi^\nu$$
but given that for $\mathbf{24}$ we have a tensor:

$$\psi_\mu \phi^\nu+\psi_\nu\phi^\mu$$
I cannot see why this is so. Please can someone explain?

[ FYI the rep $\mathbf{24}$ has Young-Diagram:

[image]

]

Comment: I think this is just the following. If $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{24}$ are a basis of the $24$-dimensional representation $V$, the antisymmetric part of $V\oplus V$ is the $24$-dimension span $V^-$ of vectors of the form $(x_i,-x_i)$, $i=1,2,\ldots,24$, and the symmetric part $V^+$ is the span of vectors of the form $(x_i,x_i),i=1,2,\ldots,24$. Both $V^+$ and $V^-$ are 24-dimensional, and their sum is $V\oplus V$.

Comment: In other words, I I think *symmetric (resp. antisymmetric)* here refers to eigenspaces of $\lambda=+1$ (resp. $\lambda=-1$) of the symmetry operator $T:V\oplus V\to V\oplus V$, $T(x,y)=(y,x)$.

Comment: Hmm. But then that comment from someone else feels a bit strange. AFAICT both $\psi_\mu\phi^\nu$ and $\psi_\nu\phi^\mu$ are vectors in that $24$ dimensional rep $V$ (that I prefer to call the adjoint rep of $SU(5)$). They aren't even elements of $V\oplus V$, so how could you call them (anti)symmetric???

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I don't think both $\psi_\mu\phi^\nu$ and $\psi_\nu \phi^\mu$ are vectors in the $24$ rep. For this do we not require symmetry in the two indices?

Comment: Why would that be the case? The 24-dimensional representation I'm thinking about is a subrep (or a quotient) of the tensor product of the five dimensional natural representation and its dual. We simply want trace zero. $\mu$ and $\nu$ are both ranging from one  to five, right?

Comment: But, I'm not sure about my earlier comment any longer. The way I described $V^+$ and $V^-$ those are isomorphic to the 24-dimensional rep. Anything else would violate Jordan-Hölder :-)

Comment: So, what **is** your description of the antisymmetric (resp. symmetric) part of $V\oplus V$?